# Tkinter callback() "TypeError: callback() takes 1 positional argument but 4 were given"

Tags: python, tkinter, addition, trace

When I type into the entrybox, while i expect the console to print what i've typed the following error is raised:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/tkinter/__init__.py", line 1892, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
TypeError: callback() takes 1 positional argument but 4 were given
```

```py
class Editor:

    
    def __init__(self,master):
         
        self.master = master
        self.edit_frame = tk.Frame(self.master)
        self.elem_frame = tk.Frame(self.master)
        self.naz = Nazioni()
        paesi = [*self.naz.iso3]
        print(paesi)
        self.comb_paese = ttk.Combobox(self.edit_frame, value = paesi)
        self.comb_paese.current(1)
        
        
        self.kwordvar= tk.StringVar()
        entry_keyword = tk.Entry(self.edit_frame, textvariable=self.kwordvar)

        self.kwordvar.trace_add("write",self.callback)
 
        
        writer = tk.Text(self.edit_frame)
        writer.grid(row=0,column=0)
        entry_keyword.grid(row=1, column=1) 
        self.comb_paese.grid(row=1, column = 0)
        self.elem_frame.grid(row=0, column = 1)
        self.edit_frame.grid(row=0,column=0)
                    
           


    def callback(self):
          print(self.kwordvar)
```

The `Editor` class is being called with  `self.newWindow= tk.Toplevel(self.master)` as argument, don't know if it has anything to do here but while searching for a solution I've read something about it.

Comment: The callback for `trace_add` expects three extra arguments. If you don't need them, just add `*args` in the definition of `callback()`, i.e. `def callback(self, *args)`.